# what is the method to echo class attribute inside the i tag?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, iframe

I am having line like below and it works fine.

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'amenities' ) . '"> <i class="fab fa-safari" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
```

the code contains i tag for font-awesome. its like

```
<i class="fab fa-safari" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>
```

---

---

*Now my problem is when i am trying to echo the class inside using the below code it simply does not work.*

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'amenities' ) . '"><i class="'.the_field('acf_wppl_field_icon','amenities'.'_'. $term->term_id).'"></i> ' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
```

the i tag now is

```
<i class="'.the_field('acf_wppl_field_icon','amenities'.'_'. $term->term_id).'"></i>
```

the code does work it gets field but output like this strangely..the field comes out of the iframe and gets echoed out of the list elements

```
  <div>
   <ul>fa-glass
<li><a href="http://securesa.online/lamat/drinks/"> <i class="" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>Drinks</a></li>fas fa-utensils<li><a href="http://securesa.online/lamat/food/"> <i class="" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>Food</a></li>fas fa-futbol<li><a href="http://securesa.online/lamat/sports/"> <i class="" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>Sports</a></li>fas fa-wifi<li><a href="http://securesa.online/lamat/wifi/"> <i class="" style="font-size:25px;color:#981111"></i>Wifi</a></li></ul>              </div>
```

Really appreciate the help

Comment: Just for information: The `i` tag has nothing to do with an `iframe`. https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_i.asp

Comment: oh sorry i have changed it

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the plugin ACF.

It has to be (`get_field()`)

```
<i class="'.get_field('acf_wppl_field_icon','amenities'.'_'. $term->term_id).'"></i>
```

instead of  (`the_field()`)

```
<i class="'.the_field('acf_wppl_field_icon','amenities'.'_'. $term->term_id).'"></i>
```